# Entity Framework - Include only specific array-elements of an array-property into the HTTP-Response

Tags: c#, entity-framework

let's say I have these classes:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id {...}
    public List<Bar> Bars {...}
}

public class Bar {
    public int Id {...};
    public DateTime Date {...};
}
```

Now imagine this GET-Request:

```
"/home/foo/1/1" ( [controller]/[action]/[id]/[month] )
```

I want to return a specific `Foo` with its `Bars` only from the month specified in the URL.

How would I do that?

I tried something like this, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
return await _context.Foo.Include(f => f.Bars.FindAll(b => b.Date.Month == month));
```

Some help here would be really nice, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Assumed you have a parameter called `fooId` from the query.

```
_context.Foo
    .Where(f => f.Id == fooId)
    .Select(f => new
        {
            Id = f.Id,
            Bars = f.Bars.Where(b => b.Date.Month == month).ToList()
        })
    .ToList()
    .Select(a => new Foo
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            Bars = a.Bars
        })
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

*NOTE: Converting from anonymous type back to Foo probably isn't necessary if you're just going straight from this to JSON serialisation.*